# Move AWS s3 deleted files to Glacier

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Bucket on s3 where we store many images for our sites.  We have enabled versioning on this bucket.

I want that the deleted images (they get a marker as Deleted) to get moved automatically to Glacier since its lot cheaper.

I have set a LifeCycle that after 1 day the previous version to be moved to Glacier....but is not working...I am missing something but not sure what.

[image: files versions]

[image: rule]

thanks!

Comment: Make that 1 to 0 for "Archive to glacier storage class" and then see if it works

Comment: "After 1 day" doesn't mean precisely 24 hours, and it looks like you posted this question not long after the 24 hour mark.   The object becomes *eligible* for consideration when it reaches the age specified in the lifecycle policy but you should not expect it to change its storage class until some time between n days and n + 1 days... hence, the suggestion from @error2007s to change the value to 0, which may not be what you want, since things may disappear prematurely.  Use caution with 0 because Glacier has documented penalty charges for not keeping objects in it for at least 90 days.

Comment: Hello!thanks , but still didnt ge moved to glacier...I will check tomorrow lets see ;)

Comment: ok, I have just checked and they did get moved to glacier!! awesome! thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

As michael comments:

> "After 1 day" doesn't mean precisely 24 hours, and it looks like you posted this question not long after the 24 hour mark. The object becomes eligible for consideration when it reaches the age specified in the lifecycle policy but you should not expect it to change its storage class until some time between n days and n + 1 days...